Expired passport and flight tomorrow
Tomorrow I am flying from Eindhoven airport to London Stansted. My friend has an expired passport. The passport expired in February this year. We cannot get a new passport anymore but we could get a "Noodpaspoort" (emergency passport). I have called the Dutch Marechaussee and they said we could get a noodpaspoort at the airport.
Does anybody know if this is correct? Because they told me to get one at the Marechaussee, but they told my friend he could get one at bruno paspoort. I also could not find anything called bruno paspoort.

There seems to be a book called Het paspoort by one Bruno Frank, but aside from that I can also find nothing relating to "Bruno paspoort."
There's a chance that they had in mind some private company that will handle the application on your behalf.  I tend to doubt that such services exist in the Netherlands for passports, because passport applications must always be made in person.
I would therefore ignore that if I were you and just get (your friend) to the Marechaussee.  First you might want to read this, which explains what your friend will need to present to obtain the emergency passport: Wanneer en hoe kan ik een noodpaspoort krijgen?
In brief, your friend will need evidence that he is traveling soon (such as the plane tickets), his existing expired passport, valid proof of identity (a driver's license is acceptable), and  a recent photograph that meets the standards for passport photos.
There is also a link to a page listing the offices that issue emergency passports.
Some countries do not accept emergency passports, or accept them only with limitations (for example, the US requires you to have a visa with an emergency passport; you cannot use the visa waiver program/ESTA).  The UK does accept them:

Emergency travel documents are issued by governments. They are usually for specific journeys. The [entry clearance officer] should normally consider them satisfactory documents for travel to the United Kingdom.


Thank you for your answer. This makes me a little more at ease. We both have contacted the Marechaussee again, we got a bit more information this time. We can go to the airport. They have an office there that can help us. They did tell us that a proof of identity was not needed, only the expired passport and passport photos were enough. This is because the passport is newly expired. Thank you for the help!

Great answer, @dev_helemaaldebom might like to know as well that with their fetching pink noodpaspoort at Stansted they should follow the directions for UK/EU etc citizens but should not join the ePassport gate queue since their passport will not be biometric. Instead they should join the 'family' queue to speak to a border officer.

@MJeffryes good point.  The reason the US does not accept these passports for the VWP is that they lack the RFID chip; this of course means that most automated gates will also be unable to handle them.
